# Python: Change Tuple Order in List Of Tuples

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples like so:

```
ListOfTuples = [(var1,var2,var3,var4,var5), 
    (var6,var7,var8,var9,var10), 
    (var11,var12,var13,var14,var15),
    (var16,var17,var18,var19,var20)]
```

I want to swap two tuples, i.e. have the list like:

```
ListOfTuples = [(var1,var2,var3,var4,var5), 
    (var6,var7,var8,var9,var10), 
    (var16,var17,var18,var19,var20)
    (var11,var12,var13,var14,var15)]
```

I have tried the following unsuccessfully:

```
ListOfTuples[2], ListOfTuples[3] = ListOfTuples[3] , ListOfTuples[2]
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this please?

Comment: The code you posted is correct... Why do you think it was unsuccessful?

Comment: are you trying to sort it in any way in particular?

Comment: @Aaron: The swapping is part of an if statement - if a condition is true then swap the tuples, otherwise pass.

Comment: @interjay: The code is part of a CGI script.  When I comment out the code above it works, when I leave it in it doesn't.

Comment: @user725236: Huh? what does "it works" mean? The question as you posted it can't be answered unless you provide meaningful information.

Comment: Your question is useless. Why can't you put the code after an `if` statement? And what does "works"/"doesn't work" mean, with regards to what code and input?

Comment: @interjay:  "it works" means that I get the output I should, "it doesn't" means it throws a server error (rather than a Python error).

Comment: If your script works with that code commented out, remove the code and you have your solution. That's the best answer that can be given with the given information.

Comment: What server error? What's the log output like? Please show us exactly what you''re doing, tell us why the server cares what the tuples are, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code working fine for me. I have also tried code below and it works for me:

```
data = [(1,2,3), (3,4,5), (5,6,7), (7,8,9)]
data[2:] = reversed(data[2:])
>>> [(1, 2, 3), (3, 4, 5), (7, 8, 9), (5, 6, 7)]
```

I have tried this in the following way to use condition:

```
data = [(1,2,3), (3,4,5), (5,6,7), (7,8,9)]
for i,x in enumerate(data):
    if i+1 < len(data) and x[0] < data[i+1][0]:        
        data[i], data[i+1] = data[i+1], data[i]
>>> [(3, 4, 5), (5, 6, 7), (7, 8, 9), (1, 2, 3)]
```

Comment: Might want to say specifically `data[2:3] = reversed(data[2:3])` since his example data has more than three columns.

Comment: @Artsiom Rudzenka:  I am looking for a way of reversing data[i] and data[i+1], for data[n] number of tuples, rather than data[2] and data[3] specifically.

Answer (score -2):

hope this would help:

```
temp = ListOfTuples[2]
ListOfTuples[2] = ListOfTuples[3]
ListOfTuples[3] = temp
```

Comment: -1, this does the same as the code in the question, but in a less Pythonic manner.